# How to filter array by random key-value pair

Tags: swift, filter

I have a model like this

```
struct World {
    var country: String
    var city: String
}

  var world = [ World(country: "USA", city: "New York"),
                World(country: "USA", city: "California"),
                World(country: "France", city: "Paris"),
                World(country: "Italy", city: "Milano") ]
```

I would like to filter array by dictionary which looks like this `["country": "USA", "city": "New York", "country": "France", "city": "Milano"]`. The problem is it's always not in the same order. So, next dictionary could be like `["city": "New York", "city": "Milano", "country": "USA"]`.

I tried like this.

```
dictionary.forEach { (arg) in
            let (key, val) = arg
            world.filter({$0.key == val})
}
```

but error says

> Value of type 'World' has no member 'key'

How can I achieve this? Thank you in advance!

**Edit**

Here is my whole code

```
import UIKit

struct World {
    var country: String
    var city: String
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet var tableVIew: UITableView!

    var sectionName = ["country", "city"]
    var array = ["USA", "Italy", "France"]
    var array1 = ["New York", "Milano", "Paris"]
    var world = [ World(country: "USA", city: "New York"),
                  World(country: "USA", city: "California"),
                  World(country: "France", city: "Paris"),
                  World(country: "Italy", city: "Milano") ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

         tableVIew.delegate = self
         tableVIew.dataSource = self
    }

    @IBAction func done(_ sender: Any) {
        print(gotDic)
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sectionName.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sectionName[section]
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return array.count
        }
        else if section == 1 {
            return array1.count
        }
        else{
            return 0
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableVIew.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]
        case 1:
            cell.textLabel?.text = array1[indexPath.row]
        default:
            break
        }
        return cell
    }

    var gotDic = [ String : String ]()

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let index = tableVIew.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let section = indexPath.section
        let currentCell = tableVIew.cellForRow(at: index!)
        let secName = sectionName[section]
        let text = currentCell!.textLabel!.text

        if currentCell?.accessoryType == .checkmark {
            gotDic.removeValue(forKey: text!)
            currentCell?.accessoryType = .none
        } else {
            gotDic.updateValue(secName, forKey: text!)
            currentCell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }
        print(gotDic)
    }    
}
```

Comment: `"country": "USA", "city": "New York", "country": "France", "city": "Milano"]` your data format is broken. It doesn't retain the association between coutry and city.

Comment: @Alexander it is probably an array of dictionaries `[["country": "USA", "city": "New York"],[ "country": "Italy", "city": "Milano"]]`

Comment: Where is your dictionary defined ?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is in multi selectable tableview, two section. "country" and "city. and I want to fetch which section and which row was selected and filter by result. Does that make sense?

Comment: Do you want to filter one section based on what is selected in the other section?

Answer (score 1):

Your `world` object is not a dictionary, but an Array with `World` items in it.  To filter the `world` list to only contain the "USA" countries you can do the following:

```
let val = "USA"
let result = world.filter({$0.country == val})
```

The result will be

```
[World(country: "USA", city: "New York"), World(country: "USA", city: "California")]
```

To filter by city and country

```
let country = "USA"
let city = "New York"
let result = world.filter({$0.country == country && $0.city == city})
```

The result will be

```
[World(country: "USA", city: "New York")]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. **FYI:** Dictionaries are **unordered** collections of key-value associations. Each key **must be unique**.
2. Your `gotDic` would look like `["New York": "city", "France": "country", "Milano": "city", "USA": "country"]`

You are probably searching for sth like:

```
let userSelection = Array(gotDic.keys)
let result = world.filter {
    userSelection.contains($0.city) && userSelection.contains($0.country)
}
```